# exam document class and pdflscape causing unwanted margin changes

Tags: margins, exam, pdflscape

I'm having problems with the margins when using the exam document class and the package pdflscape. When I insert a landscape page in the middle of my exam document, it drastically widens the bottom margins of all subsequent portrait pages and the left margins of subsequent landscape pages.

Minimal working example (updated):

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\headrule
\footrule

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question This is the first page. 
  \newpage
  
  \question This is a second normal page.

  \begin{landscape}
    \question This is in landscape. The left margin is much wider.
  \end{landscape}
  
  \newgeometry{margin=3cm}
  \question This is in portrait. The margins are fixed using newgeometry.

  \begin{landscape}
    \newgeometry{margin=3cm}
    \question This is another page in landscape. The left margin is still affected.
  \end{landscape}

  \question This is another page in portrait. The margins are normal.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions or alternatives?

Edit: The `\newgeometry[margin=length]` fix works outside of the `questions` and related environments, but it doesn't inside the `questions` environment. I have updated my MWE to reflect this.

Comment: the landscape page is short because `\textheight` has the same value as `\textwidth` it's not being set back to the original value. Not sure why. (thanks for good test document )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit

If you aren't set on using the `exam`-package, I've found an alternative – [`exsheets`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\section{Your favorite subject, ever!}
\begin{question}{10}
    This is our very first very difficult to solve question!
\end{question}
\begin{question}{4}
    Explain your decision for the answer above.

    \blank[width=5\linewidth,linespread=1.5]{}
\end{question}

\begin{landscape}
\section{Your least favorite subject, yes, you'll have to answer these questions, too!}

\begin{question}{1}
    What is my favorite toy?
\end{question}

\begin{question}{2}
    And what my favorit animal?
\end{question}

\lipsum[3]

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Seems to work well:

[image: exsheets]

## Previous attempts at solving this

David Carlisle is right, the margins don't get reset after `\end{landscape}`.

You could work with geometry to fix this:

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

\headrule
\footrule

\begin{document}
This is the first page. 
\newpage

This is a second normal page.

\begin{landscape}
  This is in landscape. The margins are not affected.
\end{landscape}

\newgeometry{margin=3cm}
This is in portrait. The bottom margin is much wider.

\begin{landscape}
  This is another page in landscape. Now the left margin is affected.
\end{landscape}

\newgeometry{margin=3cm}
This is another page in portrait. The margins are still affected.
\end{document}
```

[image: newgeometry]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I've found it doesn't work with the document I'm working on. I've done some troubleshooting, and I've found your fix to not work in the `questions` environment for some reason. Do you have any other suggestions? (Also, should I modify my MWE to reflect this?)

Comment: @azsr, yes, please do give us a **complete** mwe. We can only test what you provide.

Comment: Alright, I have updated my MWE. Sorry for being too minimal the first time around.

Comment: @azsr, I suspect the geometry isn't restored due to all the questions having to be placed in the same environment. Maybe the group has to end before `\restoregeometry` takes effect.

Comment: Ah, well that sucks. I'm probably going to live with changing around the sequence of my pages for now until a better alternative comes about. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @azsr, I've found another way to typeset an exam, see the edit.

Comment: Looks quite promising! I'll use them on other assignments, and I'll accept this answer until a solution for the exam class comes about. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you think the original problem was weird, try this version.

BTW, I previously discovered that pdflscape does not change `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`, so `\newgeometry` does not correctly calculate `\textwidth` and `\textheight`.  See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/556942/how-to-fit-pdf-page-in-custom-page-size-in-the-mid-document)

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\headrule
\footrule

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question This is the first page. 
  \newpage
  
  \fullwidth{height=\the\textheight, width=\the\linewidth, or \the\textwidth}
  \question This is a second normal page.

  \begin{landscape}
    \fullwidth{height=\the\textheight, width=\the\linewidth, or \the\textwidth}
    \question This is in landscape. The left margin is much wider.
  \end{landscape}
  
  \newgeometry{margin=3cm}
  \question This is in portrait. The margins are fixed using newgeometry.

  \begin{landscape}
    \newgeometry{margin=3cm}
    \fullwidth{height=\the\textheight, width=\the\linewidth, or \the\textwidth}
    \question This is another page in landscape. The left margin is still affected.
  \end{landscape}

  \question This is another page in portrait. The margins are normal.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I'm reading your example correctly -- it's normal on page 2, but on page 3 it makes a "square" for text but not for the line (?), and on page 5 it's really messed up. Interesting... I'm still relatively green on LaTeX, so I'm not sure if I interpreted that correctly.

Comment: The landscape environment does not change \textwidth, only \textheight and \linewidth, which is why I printed both.  In fact, I use `\ifdim\textheight=\textwidth` to detect landscape pages.