# Is it possible to add a margin worth of more page space to an existing a4paper?

Tags: margins, paper-size

I am aware that for something like `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}`, the page shape is now A4. Using the `geometry` package only allows you to play with the margin size. However, is it possible to add, say `3cm` of extra paper on either the left or right side of the A4 paper.

I understand that the shape is now no longer A4, but I still want to know if that is possible. So all the main text and the original document is within the A4 paper, but any additional notes can now be placed in the new "margin" paper.

Comment: geometry package lets you set the paper size to any lengths

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/556942/how-to-fit-pdf-page-in-custom-page-size-in-the-mid-document

Comment: Well, if you specify `a4paper` then A4 is the size, so why set that if you don't want A4?